# Efficiently sum a small numpy array, broadcast across a ginormous numpy array?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I want to calculate an indexed weight sum across a large (1,000,000 x
3,000) boolean numpy array.  The large boolean array changes
infrequently, but the weights come at query time, and I need answers
very fast, without copying the whole large array, or expanding the
small weight array to the size of the large array.

The result should be an array with 1,000,000 entries, each having the
sum of the weights array entries corresponding to that row's True
values.

I looked into using masked arrays, but they seem to require building a
weights array the size of my large boolean array.

The code below gives the correct results, but I can't afford that copy
during the multiply step.  The multiply isn't even necessary, since
the values array is boolean, but at least it handles the broadcasting
properly.

I'm new to numpy, and loving it, but I'm about to give up on it for
this particular problem.  I've learned enough numpy to know to stay
away from anything that loops in python.

My next step will be to write this routine in C (which has the added
benefit of letting me save memory by using bits instead of bytes, by
the way.)

Unless one of you numpy gurus can save me from cython?

```
from numpy import array, multiply, sum

# Construct an example values array, alternating True and False.
# This represents four records of three attributes each:
#    array([[False,  True, False],
#           [ True, False,  True],
#           [False,  True, False],
#           [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
values = array([(x % 2) for x in range(12)], dtype=bool).reshape((4,3))

# Construct example weights, one for each attribute:
#    array([1, 2, 3])
weights = array(range(1, 4))

# Create expensive NEW array with the weights for the True attributes.
# Broadcast the weights array into the values array.
#    array([[0, 2, 0],
#           [1, 0, 3],
#           [0, 2, 0],
#           [1, 0, 3]])
weighted = multiply(values, weights)

# Add up the weights:
#    array([2, 4, 2, 4])
answers = sum(weighted, axis=1)

print answers

# Rejected masked_array solution is too expensive (and oddly inverts
# the results):
masked = numpy.ma.array([[1,2,3]] * 4, mask=values)
```

Comment: Great job with the example of what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot product (or inner product) is what you want. It allows you to take a matrix of size `m×n` and a vector of length `n` and multiply them together yielding a vector of length `m`, where each entry is the weighted sum of a row of the matrix with the entries of the vector of as weights.

Numpy implements this as `array1.dot(array2)` (or `numpy.dot(array1, array2)` in older versions). e.g.:

```
from numpy import array

values = array([(x % 2) for x in range(12)], dtype=bool).reshape((4,3))

weights = array(range(1, 4))

answers = values.dot(weights)
print answers
# output: [ 2 4 2 4 ]
```

(You should benchmark this though, using the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).)

Comment: senderle included a quick benchmark with his answer; this performed well.

Comment: This is awesome, I didn't understand the dot function at all from my wandering through the docs.  I did time it, and unfortunately it's not quite fast enough even on my high CPU ec2 instance, but this exactly what I asked for, and I'm glad to know about it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that [dbaupp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10220357/577088)'s answer is the correct one. But just for the sake of diversity, here's another solution that saves memory. This will work even for operations that don't have a built-in `numpy` equivalent.

```
>>> values = numpy.array([(x % 2) for x in range(12)], dtype=bool).reshape((4,3))
>>> weights = numpy.array(range(1, 4))
>>> weights_stretched = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(weights, (4, 3), (0, 8))
```

`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` is a wonderful little function! It allows you to specify `shape` and `strides` values that allow a small array to mimic a much larger array.  Observe -- there aren't *really* four rows here; it just looks that way:

```
>>> weights_stretched[0][0] = 4
>>> weights_stretched 
array([[4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 3]])
```

So instead of passing a huge array to `MaskedArray`, you can pass a smaller one. (But as you've already noticed, `numpy` masking works in the opposite way you might expect; truth masks, rather than revealing, so you'll have to store your `values` inverted.) As you can see, `MaskedArray` doesn't copy any data; it just reflects whatever is in `weights_stretched`:

```
>>> masked = numpy.ma.MaskedArray(weights_stretched, numpy.logical_not(values))
>>> weights_stretched[0][0] = 1
>>> masked
masked_array(data =
 [[-- 2 --]
 [1 -- 3]
 [-- 2 --]
 [1 -- 3]],
      mask =
 [[ True False  True]
 [False  True False]
 [ True False  True]
 [False  True False]],
      fill_value=999999)
```

Now we can just pass it to sum:

```
>>> sum(masked, axis=1)
masked_array(data = [2 4 2 4],
      mask = [False False False False],
      fill_value=999999)
```

I benchmarked numpy.dot and the above against a 1,000,000 x 30 array. This is the result on a relatively modern MacBook Pro (`numpy.dot` is `dot1`; mine is `dot2`):

```
>>> %timeit dot1(values, weights)
1 loops, best of 3: 194 ms per loop
>>> %timeit dot2(values, weights)
1 loops, best of 3: 459 ms per loop
```

As you can see, the built-in `numpy` solution is faster. But `stride_tricks` is worth knowing about regardless, so I'm leaving this.

Comment: stride_tricks is worth knowing to be sure!  I wondered if something like that were possible, and tried to see if arrays could be constructed by reference, but gave up.  I can imagine using this in the future, thanks!

Comment: how did you come up with the third argument? Why is it (0, 8)?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
a = np.array([sum(row * weights) for row in values])
```

This uses `sum()` to immediately sum the `row * weights` values, so you don't need the memory to store all the intermediate values.  Then the list comprehension collects all the values.

You said you want to avoid anything that "loops in Python".  This at least does the looping with the C guts of Python, rather than an explicit Python loop, but it can't be as fast as a NumPy solution because that uses compiled C or Fortran.

Comment: I will leave this up, but @dbaupp nailed it.  A pure NumPy solution is going to be better than this.

Comment: Yes, pure numpy is a win, but this is a nicely succinct solution as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need numpy for something like that. And 1000000 by 3000 is a huge array; this will not fit in your RAM, most likely.

I would do it this way:

Let's say that you data is originally in a text file:

```
False,True,False
True,False,True
False,True,False
True,False,True
```

My code:

```
weight = range(1,4)    
dicto = {'True':1, 'False':0}

with open ('my_data.txt') as fin:

    a = sum(sum(dicto[ele]*w for ele,w in zip(line.strip().split(','),weight)) for line in fin)
```

Result:

```
>>> a
12
```

EDIT:

I think I slightly misread the question first time around, and summed up the everything together. Here is the solution that gives the exact solution that OP is after:

```
weight = range(1,4)
dicto = {'True':1, 'False':0}

with open ('my_data.txt') as fin:

    a = [sum(dicto[ele]*w for ele,w in zip(line.strip().split(','),weight)) for line in fin]
```

Result:

```
>>> a
[2, 4, 2, 4]
```

Comment: A 1000000 by 3000 array of 32-bit float values works out to about 11.2 GiB of data.  If his true/false values are single-byte values, that's only about 2.8 GB of data.  There are 64-bit computers with 32GB or more of RAM, so even the float array might fit depending on his computer.  But he won't want to make any copies of it if he can help it!

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks. I know that there is no way it would fit in my RAM! Just wanted to have this solution in case size is an issue.

Comment: steveha is right, they're single-byte (dtype=bool) values and it's feasible to keep them in ram.  And with my performance requirements, I really can't afford to touch the disk at all, even to swap.  But I agree that this is a useful addition for someone looking to do the same thing on a slower time scale, with less ram, thanks!